# Should I Bind a model property to View's progressbar value in this situation or other better way to do?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I had a MVVM Application. I need to get data from hardware through an .Net DLL function.
I put a progress bar in the View to display the progress of the get data status.
But My "get data" function is put in my Model Class (logic process), not in the ViewModel, and the background work is also create in Model's function.
I set a integer property in model class to save the bk worker's ProgressPercentage. Should I Binding the Views progress bar property to Model's property?
Or have other best way to do this...

thanks...

Comment: If you want to follow MVVM then generally the View binds to the ViewModel and **not** directly to the Model.  Sounds like  you have no ViewModel

Comment: move integer property from  Model to ViewModel than bind a progress bar to it. Use your Model to  set this property.

Comment: Hi MickyD~
I have viewmodel and I put the get data function in the viewmodel int the first. However, I think the get data function is pure business logic, so I want to move it to Model. and then the question happen~~

Comment: Hi VitaliyK~~How to set VM's property from Model? Model doesn't have the instance of VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to move the 'GetData' method out of the Model and into a 'Service'. This service should then publish an event whenever the progress changes. The ViewModel then subscribes to this event and sets a property on the ViewModel using the UI thread. You can do this using the PubSubEvents of [PRISM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122(v=pandp.40).aspx) and "ThreadOption.UIThread".